# XML Parsing using C# from API Response

Tags: c#, xml

i am getting response from an API like this

```
<OrbiscomResponse IssuerId="5" ReturnCode="Success" Version="12.2">
    <CreateApprovedPurchaseResponse PurchaseId="87654321" Status="A">
        <CPN AVV="123" Expiry="1407" Id="123456789" PAN="5555444433332222"</CPN>
    </CreateApprovedPurchaseResponse>
</OrbiscomResponse>
```

I want to save the **PurchaseId**, **AVV**, **Expiry**, **PAN** into my local database. Kindly let me know how can i retrieve the data related with these values from **XML** using **C#**.

Comment: One of the approaches it to use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Try using that and post a question if you have any specific issues.

Comment: i tried this one, But i am not getting the desired output!

Comment: It always helps if you post valid XML in your question - your `CPN` element is not correctly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<OrbiscomResponse IssuerId=\"5\" ReturnCode=\"Success\" Version=\"12.2\">" +
                    "<CreateApprovedPurchaseResponse PurchaseId=\"87654321\" Status=\"A\">" +
                        "<CPN AVV=\"123\" Expiry=\"1407\" Id=\"123456789\" PAN=\"5555444433332222\"/>" +
                    "</CreateApprovedPurchaseResponse>" +
                "</OrbiscomResponse>";

            XElement response = XElement.Parse(xml);

            int purchaseId = int.Parse(response.Descendants("CreateApprovedPurchaseResponse").Attributes("PurchaseId").FirstOrDefault().Value);
            int avw = int.Parse(response.Descendants("CPN").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("AVV").Value); 
            int expiry = int.Parse(response.Descendants("CPN").Attributes("Expiry").FirstOrDefault().Value);
            string pan = response.Descendants("CPN").Attributes("PAN").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
    }
}
​
```